# Display RecordType Name on a LWC datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, record-type

I am running into an issue getting the recordType Name to display on my LWC. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

clientside js:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import getTrackingData from "@salesforce/apex/OneHourTranslationClientApex.getTrackingTranslationObject";

const columns = [
  { label: "Name", fieldName: "Name", Type: "text" },
  { label: "Type", fieldName: "recordType.Name", type: "text" },
  { label: "language", fieldName: "Language_Options__c", type: "text" },
  { label: "OHT Project Id", fieldName: "Project_Id__c", type: "text" },
  { label: "Translation Complete", fieldName: "Project_Completed__c", type: "text" }
];

export default class TranslationTrackingDataTable extends LightningElement {
  data = [];
  columns = columns;

  async connectedCallback() {
    const data = await getTrackingData();
    this.data = data;
    console.log(`this is the data ${JSON.stringify(this.data)}`);
  }
}
```

APEX Serverside Code:

```
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<TranslationTracking__c> getTrackingTranslationObject() {
    List<TranslationTracking__c> TranslationObjects = [SELECT Name, RecordType.Name , Expertise_Options__c, Language_Options__c, Project_Id__c, Project_Completed__c FROM TranslationTracking__c];
    for (TranslationTracking__c translation : TranslationObjects) {
      translation.Language_Options__c = languageTranslationStore.getLanguageName(translation.Language_Options__c);
    }
    return TranslationObjects;
  }
```

[image]

this should display the recordType.Name for each record.

Comment: Try `fieldName: "RecordType.Name"` (as this is case sensitive) but if that doesn't work you will have to flatten the data in JS. AFAIC data table OOBE doesn't support unpacking dot notation like this

Comment: Thanks! Did not work. I will manipulate in clientside js

Comment: I have tried to modify the on the js side by adding a .foreach loop however I am getting the following issue: ```[Cannot add property recordType, object is not extensible]``` the value I am assigning to recordType is the string value of what I want to output in the datatable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flatten your data in the front end as shown below

```
const columns = [
  { label: "Name", fieldName: "Name", Type: "text" },
  { label: "Type", fieldName: "recordTypeName", type: "text" },
  { label: "language", fieldName: "Language_Options__c", type: "text" },
  { label: "OHT Project Id", fieldName: "Project_Id__c", type: "text" },
  { label: "Translation Complete", fieldName: "Project_Completed__c", type: "text" }
];

if (this.data) {
    let newArray = [];
    this.data.forEach(tracking => {
        let newTracking = {};
        newTracking.Name = tracking.Name;
        newTracking.recordTypeName = recordTypeName.RecordType.Name;
        newTracking.Expertise_Options__c = newTrackingExpertise_Options__c;
        ..
        ..
        // and so on for other fields
        newArray.push(newTracking);
    });
    this.tableData = newArray;
}
```

Now tie back the `tableData` to the lightning:datatable

You can also use [Array Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and map function to simplify. Credit to sfdcfox pointing me towards this,

```
this.tableArray = this.data.map(row => ({ ...row,recordTypeName:row.RecordType.Name}))
```

Comment: `this.tableArray = this.data.map(row => ({ ...row,recordTypeName:row.RecordType.Name}))` has the same effect.

Comment: Ah that’s neat! Forgot about this array array destructuring

Comment: Thank you all my issue has been solved using your suggestions.